# What HTML tags should be read if I want to get the contents of tables on this website(web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read contents of this web page: http://cdn.ime.co.ir (Actually it's a stock market web site and I like to read prices/volumes and such contents of each table that belongs to a specific stock).
But don't know what HTML tags should I read? When I see the pages source code I can see the contents of the tables like "حجم" or "قیمت" but can't find the related values? 
I use beautifulsoup and python on Windows 10.

Comment: One option is to use [pandas read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to get a list of all tables on the page as dataframes

Comment: What are you trying to find? My developer tools have standard (ascii) table ids?

Comment: I am trying to read contents of these tables that they are volumes and prices. I am very newbie in this topic and just read a tutorial(https://codeburst.io/web-scraping-101-with-python-beautiful-soup-bb617be1f486) and liked to test it but couldn't understand what should I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can mimic POST request and pass the contract code in e.g.

```
import requests

data = {'ContractCode' : 'OSFKH98'}
r = requests.post('http://cdn.ime.co.ir/Services/Fut_Live_Loc_Service.asmx/GetContractInfo', json = data ).json()
print(r)
```

---

You could do a loop for example:

```
import requests

codes = ['OSFKH98', 'OSFOR98','OSFTR98', 'SAFKH98','SAFOR98','SAFTR98']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for code in codes:
        data = {'ContractCode' : code}
        r = s.post('http://cdn.ime.co.ir/Services/Fut_Live_Loc_Service.asmx/GetContractInfo', json = data ).json()
        print(r)
```

Example r:

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ec913bbb31164500900780c129e971f4

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't exactly understand what did you do, but it seems you grabbed all the data from the web page, so a question comes around: should I use beautifulsoup to filter data or there is better way/tool?

Comment: No. r is a dictionary containing all the contract info. You simply use standard python key value methods for accessing whatever you want

Comment: Example of r dict here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ec913bbb31164500900780c129e971f4

Comment: I also like to know how did you find the link that you used in the POST method?

Comment: The page has a timed refresh schedule which tells me it is using xhr to update so I pressed F12 in browser and looked in network tab to see how info was being retrieved. I found the url there as well as the contract codes.

Comment: Sorry for tins of questions, but like to know how can I do the above task about this page: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F# ? May you guide me about this too? This page uses get request and there is no contractcode for each stock.

Comment: Will look when home

Comment: you need to let js run so use selenium

Comment: Can you help me on this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093796/how-to-write-a-multi-threaded-program-for-plotting-interactively

Answer (score 1):

All the tables have a class `DataGridStyle` and the rows with content `Contents` so if you want all the contents of the table you should get the `td` inside all those `tr`, so the traverse would be done with `table.DataGridStyle tr.Contents > td`.

You can always try this with the javascript console, using...

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('table.DataGridStyle tr.Contents > td')

// The, per every td you would use the property `innerText`
// to get only the text with no HTML at all. For instance:
console.log(tds[5].innerText)
// "۱۳۴,۱۰۰"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for help, but I am very newbie. I couldn't understand is your code python or javascript? Where should I add your code? Can I use it inside my python program?

Comment: The code is an example of how to see in javascript in the console of the very same page.

In the case of your scrapper, you need to traverse to the element with the `table.DataGridStyle tr.Contents > td` part. Is the path to the content you're looking for